# Custom spaCy tagger to tag all words that are in a dictionary

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm trying spaCy to extract specific information from a text.
So I need to configure a custom tokenizer to identify them and a custom tagger to label all the words that are in an external dictionary in JSON format.

The tokenizer worked on several attempts, but the labeler has been having problems when processing simple text.
I hope that the label I will add to the words is a custom POS-Tag "UNM" and that I can attribute it to token.pos_ like all other labels "NOUN", "VERB", etc.

```
import requests

#keywords dictionary
dictionary = requests.get(
    "https://github.com/dglopes/NBR15575/raw/main/unidades_medidas.json").json()

    
#Creating the Custom Tagger
Doc.set_extension('pos_tag', default=None, force=True)

@Language.factory("keyword_pos_tagger")
class KeywordPosTagger:
   def __init__(self, name, nlp, keywords, pos_tag):
       self.keywords = keywords
       self.pos_tag = pos_tag
       #Doc.set_extension('pos_tag', default=None, force=True)

   def __call__(self, doc):
       for token in doc:
           if token.text in self.keywords:
               token._.pos_tag = self.pos_tag
       return doc

nlp = spacy.load('pt_core_news_md')


keywords = ('m²', 'm2', '(W/K)', 'ºC')
pos_tag = 'UNM' # substitua por seu rótulo POS

keyword_pos_tagger = KeywordPosTagger(nlp, 'keyword_pos_tagger', keywords, pos_tag)

config = {"nlp": nlp, "keywords": keywords, "pos_tag": pos_tag}

nlp.add_pipe('keyword_pos_tagger', config = config)
```

<**main**.KeywordPosTagger at 0x78d568e4cee0>

And when I use the custom tagger:

```
doc = nlp('A temperatura tem 159ºC ou 20 ºC. Também precisa ter 20m de largura e 14 m² de área, caso contrário terá 1 Kelvin (W/K)')
for token in doc:
   print(token.text, token._.pos_tag)
```

it returns this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3c241e1c89fd> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 doc = nlp('A temperatura tem 159ºC ou 20 ºC. Também precisa ter 20m de largura e 14 m² de área, caso contrário terá 1 Kelvin (W/K)')
      2 for token in doc:
      3    print(token.text, token._.pos_tag)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/spacy/tokens/underscore.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
     74     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any):
     75         if name not in self._extensions:
---> 76             raise AttributeError(Errors.E047.format(name=name))
     77         default, method, getter, setter = self._extensions[name]
     78         if setter is not None:

AttributeError: [E047] Can't assign a value to unregistered extension attribute 'pos_tag'. Did you forget to call the `set_extension` method?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the config settings in the `add_pipe` method through a config dict. In your code, the `keyword_pos_tagger` variable is a stranded component that's not actually added to the `nlp` pipeline. It shares the same vocab and you could use it for unit testing, but otherwise you can't add it to a pipeline when it's created like this.

```py
nlp.add_pipe("keyword_pos_tagger", config={"keywords": keywords, "pos_tag": pos_tag})
```

---

Edited to expand answer:

```py
# tested with spacy==3.7.2
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens import Token

# Creating the Custom Tagger
Token.set_extension("pos_tag", default=None, force=True)


@Language.factory("keyword_pos_tagger")
class KeywordPosTagger:
    def __init__(self, name, nlp, keywords, pos_tag):
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.pos_tag = pos_tag

    def __call__(self, doc):
        for token in doc:
            if token.text in self.keywords:
                token._.pos_tag = self.pos_tag
        return doc


nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_md")

keywords = ("m²", "m2", "(W/K)", "ºC")
pos_tag = "UNM"  # substitua por seu rótulo POS

config = {"keywords": keywords, "pos_tag": pos_tag}

nlp.add_pipe("keyword_pos_tagger", config=config)

doc = nlp(
    "A temperatura tem 159ºC ou 20 ºC. Também precisa ter 20m de largura e 14 m² de área, caso contrário terá 1 Kelvin (W/K)"
)
assert doc[16]._.pos_tag == "UNM"
```

Comment: Ok, but now it returns that extra fields are not permitted.

ConfigValidationError: 

Config validation error
keyword_pos_tagger -> keywords extra fields not permitted
keyword_pos_tagger -> pos_tag extra fields not permitted
{'nlp': <spacy.lang.pt.Portuguese object at 0x7ca5a310ec50>, 'name': 'keyword_pos_tagger', 'keywords': ['”', '°', '°C', 'ºC', 'A p,APP ', 'A t,APP ', 'APP', 'APT', 'At,APP  ', 'AVS', 'C', 'C d', 'CE', 'Ce/Cpe', (...), 'ΔTomín', 'ε'], 'pos_tag': 'UNM', '@factories': 'keyword_pos_tagger'}

Comment: Ah, you also have to switch `Language.component` to `Language.factory` and add the `name` arg after `nlp`, see: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines/#custom-components-factories

Comment: I changed some parts of the code following the steps you mentioned. But I cant figured out wheres the problema when i call the nlp on the sentence.

Comment: The script doesn't quite run as-is, let me just update the answer.

Comment: It work well, tks!
I just thought it would substitute the token.pos_ attribute, but creating a token.pos_tag works as should. abb, tks for the help!